# The new mobile interface is really hard to read

Tags: discussion, bug

The new user interface seems to have made everything really low contrast and also remove the row highlighting for tags I am interested in.

Please can these be addressed.

Comment: So search for the relevant aspects and discuss them here: [New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/289905).